# See complete history of changes in smartGit

Tags: git, smartgit

Is there a way to easily trace all the changes made to a file in smartGit?
I have looked around without success..

I want to be able to see the current version (v0) against the version before that (v-1). Then I want to be able to see two earlier versions in comparison to each other (as in v-1 against v-2 or v-1 against v-3)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Sure, that's possible.

1. Click onto the file you want to inspect in the Files tab.
2. Double-click it or hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>
3. In the opened log window, only commits dealing with your selected file are displayed now. Go through them and compare changes at the bottom of the screen.

[image: Screencast to show how to do that]

Comment: Thanks. It was cmd+L on mac and then it worked as in your picture.